LangGraph: State Management, Memory Optimization, Multiple Agents
Currently, I am working with the following stack: LangGraph, Next.js, Node.js, and pgvector (PostgreSQL).

State Management: How can I save information from the database into a state and extract only the necessary data? For example, I need to fetch data such as the product name, description, and price. However, the price should not be displayed in the chat unless the user explicitly asks for it.
Memory Optimization: How can I implement a memory system to avoid fetching the same data multiple times from the database?
Response Optimization: When fetching data from the database, the description field can contain up to 10000 characters. How can I optimize this to generate a response limited to three sentences for the user?
Multiple Agents: How can I create multiple specialized agents to handle:

Product information
Delivery status
Issue resolution


Configuring Output Formats: How can I configure different output formats for the system? For example, supporting plain text, JSON, or rich UI components for user interactions.
Integration as a Module: How can I develop the system as a reusable module that can be easily integrated into different web platforms?

